# Zero in proportion data

Tags: proportion, zero-inflation

I am counting the proportion of seeds that have germinated (RV) in petri dishes. 5 petri dishes each had 25 seeds in them. Treatment (EV) was applied. No seeds germinated. When this is put through the glm binomial in R, the P value, instead of indicating that it is significant, indicates that it is not. Other treatments, achieved at least one germination in one petri dish, and so when the glm binomial model was applied, the value of p was significant. I believe the problem is that with one of the treatments over 5 Petri dishes, the proportion is zero. I do not believe this model is accounting for the zeros properly. Any advice? Does it need to be zero-inflated?

Comment: Please clarify the circumstances; it's not clear from what you wrote. *What* comes out nonsignificant? What "summary" in R? What analysis are you doing here?  Please understand that we can't see what you see, we *only* have what you wrote to go by. A small [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) might help for concreteness.

Comment: It's not fully clear from your description but my guess is that you are experiencing "complete separation" in your regression model. The respective coefficient diverges to (minus) infinity and the standard error is even larger, leading to a non-significant result. If so, I would recommend to use bias-reduced regression instead, e.g., `brglm` in R. See the corresponding differences for more details.

Comment: It's not clear what was your experiment now which are your hypothesis. However, keep in mind that binomial tests usually don't yield significant results with small samples, and that can only be solved with larger samples.